# Max Reduction Open MP 2.0 Visual Studio 2013 C/C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openmp

I'm new here and this is my first question in this site;

I am doing a simple program to find a maximum value of a vector c that is function of two other vectors a and b. I'm doing it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and the problem is that it only support OpenMP 2.0 and I cannot do a Reduction operation to find directy the max or min value of a vector, because OpenMP 2.0 does not supports this operation.
I'm trying to do the without the constructor reduction with the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
    cMaxParcial[i] = - FLT_MAX;
}

omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
#pragma omp parallel for private (i,j,indice)
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        indice = omp_get_thread_num();

        if (c[i*N + j] > cMaxParcial[indice]){
            cMaxParcial[indice] = c[i*N + j];
            bMaxParcial[indice] = b[j];
            aMaxParcial[indice] = a[i];
        }
    }
}
cMax = -FLT_MAX;

for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
    if (cMaxParcial[i]>cMax){
        cMax = cMaxParcial[i];
        bMax = bMaxParcial[i];
        aMax = aMaxParcial[i];
    }

}
```

I'm getting the error: "The expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"
on the command `cMaxParcial[indice] = c[i*N + j];`

Can anybody help me with this error?

Comment: Can you post a full [mcve] please?

Comment: Hi, 

I commited a mistake: I declared 'indice' as a float instead a int and now I corrected it and the code runs. But I caused false sharing using static vectors and our colleagues helped me sending your codes like examples.

Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the error is caused by one of the indices not being in integer type. Since you haven't shown the code where `i`, `j`, `N` and `indice` are declared, my guess is that either `N` or `indice` is a float or double, but it would be simpler to answer if you had provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, the line above it seems to have used the same indices correctly. This leads me to believe that it's an IntelliSense error, which often are false positives. Try compiling the code and running it.

Now, on to issues that you haven't (yet) asked about (why is my parallel code slower than my serial code?). You're causing [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) by using (presumably) contiguous arrays to find the a, b, and c values of each thread. Instead of using a single `pragma` for `parallel` and `for`, split it up like so:

```
cMax = -FLT_MAX;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    float aMaxParcialPerThread;
    float bMaxParcialPerThread;
    float cMaxParcialPerThread;

    #pragma omp for nowait private (i,j)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (c[i*N + j] > cMaxParcialPerThread){
                cMaxParcialPerThread = c[i*N + j];
                bMaxParcialPerThread = b[j];
                aMaxParcialPerThread = a[i];
            } // if
        } // for j
    } // for i
    #pragma omp critical 
        {
            if (cMaxParcialPerThread < cMax) {
                cMax = cMaxParcialPerThread;
                bMax = bMaxParcialPerThread;
                aMax = aMaxParcialPerThread;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Avi Ginsburg,

The problem was exactly what you said: I declared the variable 'indice' as a float instead of int. I corrected it on code and it works!

Comment: I'm a begginer in Open MP and in parallel programming in general and I caused false sharing using static vectors in my code like you said. I'm learning it now and your code was very useful and important for improve my knowledge.  
Thanks a lot for you comment and code.

Comment: @PauloPaiva Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm glad I was able to help. If one of the answers solves your problem, or helps you the most, the appropriate action is to mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your compiler since (as far as I can see with only the partial data you gave), the code seems valid. However, it is a bit convoluted and not so good.

What about the following:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <float.h>

extern int N, NUM_THREADS;
extern float aMax, bMax, cMax, *a, *b, *c;

int foo() {
    cMax = -FLT_MAX;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads( NUM_THREADS )
    {
        float localAMax, localBMax, localCMax = -FLT_MAX;
        #pragma omp for
        for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) {
                float pivot = c[i*N + j];
                if ( pivot > localCMax ) {
                    localAMax = a[i];
                    localBMax = b[j];
                    localCMax = pivot;
                }
            }
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        {
             if ( localCMax > cMax ) {
                 aMax = localAMax;
                 bMax = localBMax;
                 cMax = localCMax;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles but I haven't tested it...
Anyway, I avoided using the `[a-c]MaxParcial` arrays since they will generate false sharing between the threads, leading to poor performance. The final reduction is done based on `critical`. It is not ideal, but will perform perfectly as long as you have a "moderated" number of threads. If you see some hot spot there or you need to use a "large" number of threads, it can be optimised better with a proper parallel reduction later.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will test your code. The problem with my code was that I declared indice as a float instead of a int. But I caused false sharing using static vectors and your code helps me to be a better programmer on it.